# unit testing a function using jasmine in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to write unit test case and code coverage to be dobe for the below code. How can i write?

```
itemClick($event: any) {
for (let obj of this.tocFiles) {
  let results = this.getchildren(obj, label);
  if (results) {
    console.log(results, 'results');
    this.clickedItem = results.children;
    break;
  }
}
}

 getchildren(obj: any, label: any) {
    if (obj.label == label) {
      return obj;
    }

    if (obj.children) {
      for (let item of obj.children) {
        let check: any = this.getchildren(item, label);
        if (check) {
          return check;
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Below is the test case I wrote,

```
it('Onclick of breadcrumb value, itemClick() to be executed',()=>{ 
  const onCLick = spyOn(component, 'itemClick'); 
  component.itemClick(undefined); 
  expect(onCLick).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
});
```

I'm still not getting this code covered under code coverage

Answer (score 0):

When you `spyOn` a method, you lose the implementation details of the function and you gain access to how it was called, how many times and with what arguments.

To get the best of both worlds, you can use `.and.callThrough()` to actually call the function and see how it was called, how many times and with what arguments.

```
it('Onclick of breadcrumb value, itemClick() to be executed',()=>{
  // !! add .and.callThrough() here 
  const onCLick = spyOn(component, 'itemClick').and.callThrough(); 
  component.itemClick(undefined); 
  expect(onCLick).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
});
```

That being said, the above test is not good because we spy on a method, we call that method and we expect for it to be called.